# Update FILEVERSION in resource file at build

Tags: c, resources, version

I have an unmanaged program (Fortran) that I'm adding a Version.rc resource file to include version information.  Is there a way to update the last number of the version information at build time with a random number generated at each build?  For example.

```
FILEVERSION = <major>,<minor>,<rev>,<build_hash>
```

where  is updated at each build and the others are input.

This question is similar to [Programmatically updating FILEVERSION in a MFC app w/SVN revision number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/108900/210778) except its not with an SVN number.

Comment: Use your favorite scripting language (or Fortran) to modify either the .rc file or a .h file that it #includes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Hans suggested above.  The best approach was to add a pre-build event in Visual Studio that runs a script (Perl in this case) to reach into the *.rc file and change the  to a random number.